# Installing Windows Server 2012 R2 hangs at "Getting Devices Ready 82%"

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a second hand HP Proliant MicroServer which I am trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2.

I get as far as entering the product key and installing the software.. However when it restarts during the install it hangs with the following message "Getting Devices Ready 82%".

I have tried wiping the hard drive and starting afresh.  I have also tried downloading the ISO file using both Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome but still get the same message.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can overcome the problem?

Answer (score 6):

#### It hangs with the following message "Getting Devices Ready 82%".

This appears to be a known issue when installing Windows Server 2012 R2 on HP Micro devices:

- A possible workaround is to disable the built-n Ethernet card in the bios before installing and then enable it again afterwards.
- Some people report having to leave it disabled and use a different NIC instead.

Please read the whole thread. I've only quoted parts of it here:

> i think it's  broadcom prolem : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\bxfcoe.sys
>
> Try to disable embeded eth card in the bios

...

> install successful on hpmicro when Embedded Ethernet card is disable

...

> Ok, I've got WSE2012 R2 to install by disabling the nic and then enabling the nic later-on

...

> Someone on a different forum posted this HP document, which documents
> this issue on page 10:
>
> http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx%2F4AA4-7658ENW.pdf?aid=38293&pbid=TnL5HPStwNw&aoid=35252&siteid=TnL5HPStwNw-ySKMMCUaDCZv2n9FoIi1qQ
>
> Good to know that HP is aware of the issue and is working with
> Microsoft on a fix.  Too bad it didn't make it into the RTM build. :(

Source [R2 Installation hangs at 84% "Getting devices ready"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b73d4be4-df04-4563-8147-7e87a5c5705c/r2-installation-hangs-at-84-getting-devices-ready?forum=winserver2012r2previewsetup)

Answer (score -2):

First try to wipe your hdd by Hiren's Boot CD's Linux Os, and then try to reinstall Windows Server again.

The Linux environment of Hiren's Boot CD has ability to entirely wipe your hdd and remove errors if any that cause failure in configuring the Windows Server.

Time elapsed in wiping process will depend on the size of your hdd.

Normally it takes 120 mins for 500GB hdd to do a clean format.

Comment: [Have you tried turning it off and on again?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)